# Make the sum of all the subtractions of a vector elements in R

Tags: r, vector, sum

Hello I am new to R and I can't find the way to do exactly what I want to. I have a vector of x numbers, and what i want to do is order it in increasing order, and then start making subtractions like this (let's say the vecto has 100 numbers for example):

```
[x(100)-x(99)]+[x(99)-x(98)]+[x(98)-x(97)]+[x(97)-x(96)]+...[x(2)-x(1)]
```

and then divide all that sum by the number of elements the vector has, in this case 100. 
The only thing that I am able to do at the moment is order the vector with:

```
 sort(nameOfTheVector)
```

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Is `x(100)` the smallest or the largest element of `x`?

Comment: @mnel I just wasnt sure whether they intended for `x(100) < x(99)` or vice-versa, which would change the signs of each difference. We had the same idea, the only difference would be what order you sort it in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`diff` returns suitably lagged and iterated differences. In your case you want the default single lag. `sum` will return the sum any arguments passed to it, so....

```
sum(diff(sort(nameOfTheVector))) / length(nameOfTheVector)
```